# Cloud Functions for Firebase invoked many times

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am just trying out Cloud Functions for Firebase in an effort to move my `firebase-queue` workers over to the cloud functions. I added a simple function to add a last updated timestamp whenever I create a new node at a given ref. The function looks like this:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.setLastUpdatedTimestamp = functions.database.ref('/nodes/{nodeId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const original = event.data.val();
    console.log('Adding lastUpdatedTimestamp to node ', original.name);
    return event.data.ref.child('lastUpdatedAtFromFC').set(Date.now());
  });
```

I deployed this cloud function and added just one node from my app. I went to the Firebase Functions dashboard and see that the function has been invoked 169 times and I have no idea why. When I look at the logs, I see logs like attaching the function to all the past nodes as well.

Is it the case that the `onWrite` would behave kind of like `child_added` and run the function for all the existing entities as well?

Would this action be repeated every time I change and deploy the function again?

I was expecting it to run just once for the newly added node.

Comment: Check the answers below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common mistake when writing functions that deal with database writes.  When you handle the event for the initial write at a location, then do a second write back to that same location, that second write will trigger yet another event that will run the function again, and so on, which will be an infinite loop.

You need some logic in your function that determines if the second write event should not re-write to the database.  That will stop the loop.  In your case, you don't need a function to set the last update time.  You can do that with a special value on the client to tell the server to insert the current time into a field.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Updating the last updated timestamp like this was not really something that I intend to do but just something that I thought will do to try out the cloud functions.

Comment: That's fair - automatically updating values like that is definitely a use case.  It just can be tricky sometimes to make sure to code in that termination case.  :-)

Comment: Yea, I am just happy I was not on a paid plan when I made this mistake. :) Don't know how much I would have been charged. I left it running overnight and I can see numerous log on the Function console that can't invoke function because the quota has reached.

Comment: Is this still the correct answer? If so, can someone update the URL as it has 404'd.

Answer (score 10):

Doug is correct. Additionally, it may be good to know that if you have a function stuck in an infinite loop, the way to get it to stop is to redeploy your function (using `firebase deploy`) with a fix for the loop, or to delete the function entirely (by removing it from your `index.js` and running `firebase deploy`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on stopping the cloud function.

Comment: Really hoping there is a way to disable functions via the admin portal in the future.. :)

Comment: You cannot remove index.js and then run `firebase deploy`. it throws `Error: functions\index.js does not exist, can't deploy Firebase Functions
`

Comment: That's true - to delete all your functions you need to remove all your functions from the `index.js`, but keep the file (empty) when you run `firebase deploy`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue. There are two questions here. How to stop an infinite loop once it's start. That's been answered. But the real question is how to add a lastUpdated date field to your objects using Firebase Cloud Function triggers.

Here's my attempt at handling the `onWrite()` loop issue.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.onWriteFeatherUpdateSummary = functions.database.ref('/messages/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      let updated = change.after.val();
      // Grab the previous value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const previous = change.before.val();
      let isChanged = true;
      let isCreated = (previous === null); // object 'created'

      // Only when the object gets updated
      if (!isCreated) {
        // An object should never directly change the lastUpdated value, this is for trhe trigger only
        isChanged = (updated.lastUpdated === previous.lastUpdated);
      }

      console.log(`isChanged: ${isChanged} ; isCreated: ${isCreated}`);

      if(isChanged) {
        // Insert whatever extra data you wnat on the update trigger
        const summary = `This is an update!`;

        // Add a 'createdDate' field on the first trigger
        if (isCreated) {
          // Make sure your object has a createdDate (Date) before the lastUpdated (Date)!
          Object.assign(updated,
              {
                createdDate : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
              }
            );
        }

        // Add lastUpdated Date field on very update trigger (but not when you just changed it with the trigger!)
        Object.assign(updated,
            {
              summary : summary,
              lastUpdated : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            }
          );
      }

      return change.after.ref.set(updated);
    });
```