# Infinite loop onWrite cloud function when writing isn't happening

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is called `onWrite` for `/searches/{id}`. It was stuck in an infinite loop, similar to what happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835339/cloud-functions-for-firebase-invoked-many-times) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865161/cloud-function-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop). Difference being, as far as I can tell, writing wasn't happening.

This same cloud function was working just fine minutes ago. I did make minor changes, but nothing is writing to the database as far as I can tell.

There is the distinct possibility that somehow writing was happening and I am mistaken. But, checking my live database, there were no changes to any of the records (currently, there is just one, so it is easy to monitor...).

The events that were being called also were marked with ids that never showed up in my database. E.g., one `event.resource` outputted as  `'projects/_/instances/sequel-tracker/refs/searches/00235180-bb4d-11e7-a598-412f4ffc71ff'` in the console, but my one record in `/searches` has a different ID.

Each event in the infinite loop seems to have a different ref path.

Any guesses on what could be happening?

Comment: Without some code, it's gonna be really difficult to say.

Comment: @DougStevenson any suggestions on what kind of code would be potentially helpful? I wouldn't want to just copy and paste the whole cloud function, but I'm not really sure why it is broken now when it was working before. Would a particular type of log be helpful?

Comment: Typically on Stack Overflow, it's expected that the question provide an MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DougStevenson well, it solved itself...I'm not really sure what happened. Thanks anyways though